# jQuery append function shows result in an increase number

Tags: jquery, append

My goal is that every time i choose an operation and press "save" button, a tag with this operation's name will appear after class change_creation. Here's my code

```
$('#operations1').on('input',function(){
        switch($(this).val()){
        case "J":
          operation_name = "J";
          document.getElementById("J").style.visibility = "visible";
        break;
        case "R":
          operation_name = "R";
          document.getElementById("R").style.visibility = "visible";    
        break;
        case "S":
          operation_name = "S";
          document.getElementById("S").style.visibility = "visible";
        break;
        case "C":
           operation_name = "C";
           document.getElementById("C").style.visibility = "visible";
        }
});
$('.button_save').click(function(){
      $('.change_creation').append('<text>'+operation_name+'</text>');
})
```

The problem is if I choose "J" for the first time, it will show one tag "J" under class change_creation, for the second, if I choose "R", it will show two "R" tags, it always increases the tag number by one every time. But what i want is just one tag for every time.
What was the problem here? Did i use append function in a wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$('.button_save').click` is getting defined everytime on you selecting any input.

```
var operation_name  = ''; //global;
$('#operations1').on('input',function(){
        switch($(this).val()){
            case "J":
                operation_name = "J";
            break;
            case "R":
                operation_name = "R";   
            break;
            case "S":
                operation_name = "S";
            break;
            case "C":
                operation_name = "C";
            }
);//ending on('input .. here
$('.button_save').click(function(){
      $('.change_creation').append('<text>'+operation_name+'</text>');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown code that runs (mismatched `{` `}` count).  My suspicion is that you creating a new `click` event handler every time `#operations1` is changed, when you should only create the click handler once (or remove the old one each time you add a new one).

Perhaps this can work for you...

```
var operation_name;

$('#operations1').on('input',function(){
    operation_name = $(this).val();
})

$('.button_save').click(function(){
    $('.change_creation').append('<text>'+operation_name+'</text>');
})
```

If this doesn't help, it would be great if you could create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't see the overall picture of how your event handlers are attached to the elements. Can it be because the event handlers are attached multiple times? How about try off() and unbind() to remove the previous hanlder:

```js
$('#operations1').off().on('input',function(){
        switch($(this).val()){
            case "J":
                operation_name = "J";
            break;
            case "R":
                operation_name = "R";   
            break;
            case "S":
                operation_name = "S";
            break;
            case "C":
                operation_name = "C";
            }

$('.button_save').unbind().click(function(){
      $('.change_creation').append('<text>'+operation_name+'</text>');
})
```